# javascript indexOf/replace multiple search terms

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have the following text:

```
var text = "aaa bbb eee ccc <br>ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk";
```

the search term is:

```
var search = "eee ggg";
```

I want to know one of the following ( equivalent ) :

a) either know through (preferrably) a regex the position (indexOf) in the text where the search term was found. In this case indexOf() should return 20. ( Notice that there is one more single **eee** before the one in **eee fff ggg***

OR

b) be able to .replace the found term **eee fff ggg** to **newinsertedstring eee fff ggg**

thanks in advance

**edit** there are some *br* in the text variable which split the lines, so it should only find it/replace it in the line which has all search terms.

Comment: I don't get it, 1. why does `eee ggg` match `eee fff ggg`? And after that question, 2. why does it not match `eee ccc ddd eee fff ggg`?

Comment: @Paul that's a good comment. there are some <br> in between so the first line is up to ddd and the second line from eee to the end

Comment: You've missed Paul's point. Your search string of `eee ggg` doesn't appear anywhere in the `text` string. Why do you expect `eee ggg` to match `eee fff ggg`?

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: There are no linebreaks in your question. Please add them and specify that it should search only line-by-line.

Comment: @nnnnnn I now understand it to be "how can I find the start of the line which contains the following words?" -- though we still do not have enough information in the question to answer it properly.

Comment: Regarding the edit, you're saying the order of the words in `search` doesn't matter, you just want to find the "line" where all terms appear?

Comment: i want to find the line where the pattern which contains eee AND ggg is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
var text = "aaa bbb eee ccc <br>ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk";
var search = /eee [^e<>]*ggg/g;

console.log(text.search(search)); // a)
console.log(text.replace(search, "newinsertedstring $&")); // b)
```

Comment: Notice that this solution will not find lines where `ggg` comes before `eee`.

Comment: yes i don't care about that

Answer (score 1):

> i want to find the line where the pattern which contains eee AND ggg is

That's a different question, but OK.

```
var text = "aaa bbb eee ccc <br>ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk",
    search = "eee ggg";

var lines = text.split("<br>"),
    terms = search.split(" "),
    firstOccurence = new RegExp(terms.join("|"));
function containedIn(l){
    return function(t) { return l.indexOf(t) > -1; }
}

for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
    if (terms.every(containedIn(lines[i]))
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace(firstOccurence, "newinsertedString $&");
var result = lines.join("<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "whatever".Replace("eee fff ggg", "newinsertedstring eee fff ggg");
```

Comment: Read the question: _the search term is: var search = "eee ggg";_